# How memory space behave after function return for local variables?

Tags: c, memory-leaks

```
void local () {
    int x = 100;

    double *loc;
    loc = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double)*100);
    memset(rxnrun, 0x0, sizeof(double)*100);

    // perform some operations


    // free(loc);
    return; // without doing free for loc variable
}
```

here, i can see what is wrong as memory leak is there for `loc` variable. But, what about variable `x`? What will happen to memory space acquired by both variable if we leave variable `x` as well as `loc` variable unattended (not free) after function return?

Will they (both variables) still acquire space?

Comment: Variable `x` is stored in stack space, hence it is popped out. Simply put the stack pointer is incremented so that space previously occupied by `x` can be overwritten. For `loc` memory is allocated from heap, hence the memory  remains allocated till the end of program, after that OS cleans it up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What and where are the stack and heap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, both the `x` and `loc` variables are local function variables, and **both variables are freed** when the function returns.

However, `loc` is a pointer and the **memory the pointer points to is what is not freed**. It's just the memory allocated by `malloc()` that is not freed.

Comment: that explains everything. It gave me a pointer where to start reading. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

All C implementations use a [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). So a local variable is on that stack (or in a register) and disappears when the called function returns.

<sup>In theory, C does not require any call stack. In practice, all C implementations use one.</sup>

In fact, a local variable is lost (so disappears) when the block (between braces) declaring it is exited. Actually, the slot on the call frame may be reused, or the variable sits in a register which is often reused for other means.

When coding in C you should think as if every local variable disappears when its block is exited. The compiler is free to implement that abstraction as it wants (generally, using a call stack, or keeping that variable in some register or some other area which will be *reused* later).

Notice that in your example both `x` and `loc` are local variables. But `loc` *contains* a pointer to a memory zone on the heap. And that zone is released by `free`

Read about [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), e.g.

```
// WRONG CODE!
int* p = 0;
{ 
   int y = 23;
   p = &y;
};
int z = *p; // undefined behavior
```

Here `y` is a local variable to the block in braces. You store its address in `p`. When you dereference that address to put its content into `z`  you have an *undefined behavior* and the *implementation* can do [anything](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) (including destroying the universe, or exploding your computer) and still be conformant to the specification of C.

<sup>What happens in reality is *unpredictable* without knowing the specific implementation and environment. Actually, and this is bad for you, the above code might not even "fault" and something could be stored in `z`.</sup>

Comment: A *call stack* is for function calls. Automatic variables may be on the call stack, or on a different stack, or not on a stack at all

Comment: Agreed. And this is what I am explaining in my second paragraph.

Comment: @MattMcNabb : I think automatic variables are always allocated on stack (may be different than call stack), Where would they be defined if not on stack?

Comment: @DontYouWorryChild I have used a system where automatic variables were not on a stack . They were in another data area.

Comment: +1 for easy links to read and sample example. I am a beginner for such questions and topics.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: which system are you thinking about? (Itanium perhaps?)

Answer (score -1):

variables x and loc will be forgotten, but memory allocated by malloc will be occupied but pointer to this memory will be forgotten.

nothing good will come.